# Android app icon shows on device to allow uninstall but does not allow to execute

Tags: android

I am able to run an android app in two virtual devices when degugging.(Galaxy tab and phone). When I close the app in debug mode the icon is not showing in the virtual device.

The same thing occurs when I load a signed .apk file to the actual devices.

The app icon shows when I go into manage applications. I can uninstall the app. Thats all I can do. I cannot launch the app since the icon is not visible with the other app icons.

I am using platform 2.2 with google api's 8.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the app icon to show with other apps and be able to launch?

Here is my manifest file.
Any help is appreciated.

```
<uses-permission 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>

<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:name=".ApplicationController"
    android:debuggable="true" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainFlippingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainFlipping" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".PrefsTabWidget"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PrefsTabWidget" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".PrefsTaskingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PrefsTasking" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SatelliteSelectionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SatelliteSelection" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="MainSettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainSettings" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="ClassificationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Classification" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="ListItemPrefActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ListItemPref" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="TimeOnTargetActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TimeOnTarget" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name="LatLonActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LatLon" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="QuantityActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Quantity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="IncidenceAngleActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.IncidenceAngle" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name="SendUrlActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SendUrl" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="TestActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Test" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="Slide"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.Slide" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Comment: Are there any warnings from the OS in logcat when you install or open the application tray?

Answer (score 2):

You should only be using `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` for one of your activities, not all of them. Try removing all others except the one that goes with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />`

EDIT: I may be wrong but I think you'll also need to capitalize MAIN as in `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` for it to be recognised as the 'main' entry point (main activity).

Comment: Thanks. that took care of the problem. I suspected the manifest file was causing the problem.

Comment: @BobSmith: Glad to help. BTW you can mark my answer as being 'accepted' by selecting the 'check' symbol to the left of my answer text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" for each activity because android project must have only one LAUNCHER activity.

Answer (score 0):

try to this if your main activity use this

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Other activity you can use this

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.(your action )" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I think it can be helpful to you .